# Is there a way to get a pickString dynamically populated in a VS Code task?

Tags: vscode-tasks

I'd like to provide a list of strings as a pickString for a task.  The list of strings will be a list of folder names, which I can get from PowerShell, but I'm not sure how to display this list in a task.

How can I set up my task and input so this list can be populated?

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0", 
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Test Task", 
      "type":  "shell", 
      "windows": {
        "command":  "echo",
          "args": [
            "-opt",
            "${input:optionsList}"
          ]
      }
    }
  ], 
  "inputs": [
    "id": "optionsList", 
    "type": "pickString", 
    "options": [<insert something here>]
  ]
}
```

I want the user to see the list of folders while the task is running.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: An enhancement request for this feature in VSCode has been requested.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109789

Please do vote for this feature through the above link. If there is more than 20 votes, then this feature would get implemented in VSCode.

Answer (score 7):

#### Problem

Actually VSCode tasks doesn't have this functionality built-in. The enhancement [request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109789) was closed probably because there is no plans to develop it in the near future.

#### Alternative Solution

You can install the [augustocdias.tasks-shell-input](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input) and configure an input variable with type `command` calling this extension for populating the pick list.

Follow the following steps:

1. Install the extension with:

   1. Search in the Extensions Sidebar (`Ctrl+Shift+X`) for `augustocdias.tasks-shell-input` and install or
   2. Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter:

   - `ext install augustocdias.tasks-shell-input`
2. Configure your `task.json` with:

   1. A task with the command you want to execute
   2. Add to the task `args` configuration entry one or more references to input variables like `${input:my_variable}`.
   3. Configure an entry in the `inputs` section with:

      - `id`: use the same variable name defined in task `args` like `my_variable` for `${input:my_variable}`
      - `type`: `command`
      - `command`: `shellCommand.execute`
      - `args`: add an config with the properties: `command`, `cwd`, `env`
3. See the example `task.json` file bellow.

#### Example

Example `task.json` file using `augustocdias.tasks-shell-input` extension:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Dynamically Populated Task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": [
                "'${input:my_dynamic_input_variable}'"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "my_dynamic_input_variable",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "shellCommand.execute",
            "args": {
                "command": "ls -1 *.*",
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "env": {
                    "WORKSPACE": "${workspaceFolder[0]}",
                    "FILE": "${file}",
                    "PROJECT": "${workspaceFolderBasename}"
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Task/Launch Input Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) shows a way to do this with a `command input variable`.  That command can come from vscode's built-in commands or from an extension.  In your case, there is no built-in command which returns a list of folders in a given workspace. But it is fairly straightforward to do it in an extension.  The documentation does not give a full example of how to do this so I'll show one here.  First the demo of it working to `ls` a chosen folder in a task:

[image: Using an extension command to populate a pickString variable].

Here is the entire `tasks.json` file:

```json
    {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "tasks": [
    
        {
          "label": "List Folder Choice files",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "ls",            // your command here
          "args": [
            "${input:pickTestDemo}"  // wait for the input by "id" below
          ],
          "problemMatcher": []
        }
      ],
      
      "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "pickTestDemo",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "folder-operations.getFoldersInWorkspace"  // returns a QuickPick element
        },
      ]
    }
```

You can see in the input variables that a command is called from the `folder-operations` extension.  Since that command returns a `QuickPick` element that is what you'll see when you run the task.

Here is the guts of the extension:

```js
    const vscode = require('vscode');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    
    /**
     * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
     */
    function activate(context) {
    
        let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.getFoldersInWorkspace', async function () {
    
        // get the workspaceFolder of the current file, check if multiple workspaceFolders
        // a file must be opened
        const wsFolders = await vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
        if (!wsFolders)  vscode.window.showErrorMessage('There is no workspacefolder open.')
        const currentWorkSpace = await vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);
    
        // filter out files, keep folder names.  Returns an array of string.
        // no attempt made here to handle symbolic links for example - look at lstatSync if necessary
    
        const allFilesFolders = fs.readdirSync(currentWorkSpace.uri.fsPath);
        const onlyFolders = allFilesFolders.filter(f => fs.statSync(path.join(currentWorkSpace.uri.fsPath, f)).isDirectory());
    
        // showQuickPick() takes an array of strings
        return vscode.window.showQuickPick(onlyFolders);
        });
    
        context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
    }
    
    exports.activate = activate;
    
    // this method is called when your extension is deactivated
    function deactivate() {}
    
    module.exports = {
        activate,
        deactivate
    }
```

Here is a link to the [folder-operations](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.folder-operations) demo extension so you can look at the full extension code and its package.json.  Once you get your extension publishing credentials set up it is really pretty easy to publish more.

Comment: but but but... when you add a new terminal in the console, it gives you exactly this list; so where's the command

Answer (score 0):

Short of installing an extension or [writing your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), you should first determine your **workspace folder structure**.

You could have

1. Single-root workspace (workspace=folder)
2. Multi-root workspace with main folder (workspace=folder)
3. Multi-root workspace with no main folder (workspace=folder/../)

There are built-in vars that allow you to access, for example

- folder path (=workspace if 1,2,3) `${workspaceFolder}`
- current file path *relative to ${workspaceFolder}* `${relativeFileDirname}`

Say you want to run `git gui` for the repo of the current open file - with `"cwd" : "${relativeFileDirname}"` in `tasks.json` config, git should pick up the current repo, and you *don't need* to ask for the folder path.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a custom task. I wanted to make use of the extension idea from @Mark and created one that could be applied more generally. [Populate-quickpick](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wiesoauch.populate-quickpick) creates options from a list provided via a text file. I am using it as a simple input for python scripts that receive the chosen option as an argument.

This is how it can be used:

```json
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "My Task",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "echo", // your command here
                "args": [
                    "${input:pickDemo}"
                ],
                "problemMatcher": []
            }
        ],
        "inputs": [
            {
                "id": "pickDemo",
                "type": "command",
                "command": "populate-quickpick.quickPickFromFile"
            }
        ]
```